# Select all movies with Rotten Tomatoes rating of 100

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, extract

data set

One of my solutions:

```
import pandas as pd
rating = 'MovieRatings.csv'
data_set=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Korisnik\Documents\dssvol03python\dss03python2023\session02\_data\MovieRatings.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data_set,columns=['FILM','Rotten Tomatoes']) 
print(df)
rt=df.sort_values(by=['Rotten Tomatoes'] ['rating'==100])
display(rt)
```

Always returns Nan

Expected the list of films rated 100 on Rotten tomatoes.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to where it clearly states a question

Comment: We don't have (and don't need) your CSV file if you follow [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/235698)

Comment: Pandas has excellent [documentation on indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) that is worth a read-through. Based on what you've shown, you should geta `KeyError`, not a `NaN` output. What is your expectation for what `['rating'==100]` is doing in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what is going on without an example (what does your data look like?), but this should select all rows where the "rating" column is equal to 100.

```py
rt = df[df["rating"] == 100]]
```

You can combine conditions as well. For example, if you had a "reviewer" column:

```py
mask = (
    (df["rating"] == 100) &
    (df["reviewer] == "Rotten Tomatoes)
)
rt = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the data set:

```
                                      FILM  IMDB  Rotten Tomatoes
```

0               Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)   7.8              NaN
1                            Cinderella (2015)   7.1              NaN
2                               Ant-Man (2015)   7.8              NaN
3                       Do You Believe? (2015)   5.4              NaN
4                Hot Tub Time Machine 2 (2015)   5.1              NaN
..                                         ...   ...              ...
141                          Mr. Holmes (2015)   7.4              NaN
142                                 '71 (2015)   7.2              NaN
143                 Two Days, One Night (2014)   7.4              NaN
144  Gett: The Trial of Viviane Amsalem (2015)   7.8              NaN
145         Kumiko, The Treasure Hunter (2015)   6.7              NaN

Comment: Use proper code formatting.   This answer is difficult to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).